# "Error: Error #1023: Stack overflow occurred." without a break or object reference

Tags: apache-flex, debugging, stack-overflow

My console window gets a set of about 15 copies of this line:

Error: Error #1023: Stack overflow occurred.
Error: Error #1023: Stack overflow occurred.
Error: Error #1023: Stack overflow occurred.
Error: Error #1023: Stack overflow occurred.
Error: Error #1023: Stack overflow occurred.
....

during operation without stopping, going into debug mode, etc.

The IDE does not break or give me any more information, so I have little idea where the problem is. I'm using the Flex SDK 4.5.1 (from the 4.7 IDE). I have looked for non-static code instantiating an object, etc. and nothing is apparent.

Any ideas?

Comment: does it happend when you launch the app or after any operation? try to reduce the scope... anyway at the of the error #1023 it should should where it happened, can you paste here the full stacktrace?

Comment: Are you sure you have a debug version of the Flash Player installed?

Comment: use traces to find the leaking spot..

Comment: THERE IS NO STACK TRACE

sorry to shout, but that's the crux of it. I get the messages and no way to get the offending line

Comment: I think @csomakk was suggesting you insert `trace()` statements in your code to give you clues to where execution is going haywire (old skool debugging, FTW). Also, I'm sure you're using the debug player, but you didn't say you were, so we still ask :) The question about the debug player is b/c of the missing line numbers in your error, but maybe that's just what happens when a stack overflow occurs in Flash.

Comment: yes, use trace(), like print() in php. if you dont know where your error, mark traces on the happy path, and find where it gets stuck.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you. The application is freakin huge so it will take weeks to bracket the error (assuming it is not coming from the player itself).

I was hoping for a extra-sensitive-break setting